# Async/await throwing exception at the end of method

Tags: c#, .net

My async method is throwing exception at the end if a condition is fulfilled. It turns out it always throws the excepion. Why? (VS 2015. NET 4.7.1)

It turns out if I add redundant return or await Task.CompletedTask it works as expected

This throws exception:

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    var date1 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);
    var date2 = new DateTime(2018,1,1);
    var t = date1 < date2;
    if (t)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

This doesn't:

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    var date1 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);
    var date2 = new DateTime(2018,1,1);
    var t = date1 < date2;
    if (t)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    return;
}
```

What's going on here?

**UPDATE**
It turned out that the exception isn't really thrown. It's just VS debugger that gives the impression of stepping into the line throwing the exception as on the screenshot below

[Visual Studio debugging screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrn6s.png)
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem on VS 2017, .NET 4.7.2 (Debug and Release configurations).

Comment: Note: the code shown has a CS1998 warning (no `await` operator): I strongly advise fixing it, but (as per other comments), this isn't an explanation

Comment: @MarcGravell: The condition is false, so the source of the exception is not clear.

Comment: @Vlad agreed, something is very odd; no repro here...

Comment: How do you call your Test method ? using "await Test()" ?

Comment: Setting `t` to true makes the exception in both examples at my system.

Comment: The code shown *looks* fine; it *could* possibly be a long-since-fixed compiler bug in the early `async` implementations (based on the VS2015); I certainly can't repro it...

Comment: In real code I'm awaiting a service that gets the date, but I wanted to make it clear in the example that exception is thrown even when condition is false. Same if I do this:
    var date1 = await Task.FromResult(new DateTime(2019, 1, 1));
    var date2 = await Task.FromResult(new DateTime(2018, 1, 1));

Comment: @PiotrSzczepaniec so to be very explicit: does the code *actually posted here* cause this behavior for you? or just the real code? So far, I don't think anyone here has managed to repro what you're seeing with the code posted here.

Comment: Turns out my problem was elsewhere. Here the exception wasn't really thrown, however when I debugged step by step, VS highlighted "throw new InvalidOperationException()" instead of skipping to the closing bracket like it does for non-async method. Happens also in VS2017

Comment: @MarcGravell in the code I posted, debugger also seems to step into the 'exception' line, but as per previous comment the exception is not thrown.

Comment: Often happens when VS/PDBs/Build outputs end up out of step. Usually best to clean the solution, close VS (maybe throw in a reboot too) before re-opening and re-building.

Comment: @PiotrSzczepaniec that looks like a build-output error, i.e. the debugger is confused as to what line it is running; it *does not* necessarily indicate an error in terms of what code is actually executed